# How to search full content of code files (e.g. SQL scripts) stored in a SharePoint folder?

Tags: sql, sharepoint, full-text-search

Do you run into this situation that there are many **code files** (e.g. SQL scripts *.sql) stored in a **SharePoint folder**, and you need to run **full text search** to find a specific one containing certain keywords (a table/column/function name, a comment, someone's initials, etc)?

Problem here is the search function in SharePoint document library only looks at the filenames, not the full content.

Of course many code repo systems (e.g. BitBucket) have advanced full text search functions (e.g. definition over usage), but in this case SharePoint hosts the "code repo", and the business depends on it...

Answer (score 0):

Through experiment I found out **SharePoint search function actually looks at the full content of a few limited file types – plain text (.txt) and Word (.doc, .docx) files**.

Since code files (*.sql, *.py, *.js, *.htm, *.css, etc) are essentially text files, we can "cheat" SharePoint by **appending ".txt" to the filename (e.g. *my_script.sql* → *my_script.sql.txt*)**, making the file content searchable once indexing finishes (in the matter of seconds according to my test).

So if you manage a SharePoint folder of many code files, you can download the entire folder as a zipped file, unzip and modify all code filenames (with utility tools to do this in batch or run a DIY script), and re-upload... voila!